# Jquery: Global variable or function not returning data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am at my wits end here.

I am trying to build a report which retrieves data from a JSON array. Which is stored in a local stored file (using HTML5 FileAPI). 
I have divided the build into two functions: Report and FileReader

I am able to read the file, and send the content to console.log inside the FileReader function. But I am NOT ABLE to send that data outside the function. I've tried so many different approaches that I've lost count on which and how many. I tried Global Variable, but that stays blank outside the FileReader Function. I tried Promise.deferred etc. etc.

Please help!

```
    var JsData = '';

    function fileReader(hente) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    fs.root.getFile(hente, {}, function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file, "utf-8");
        reader.onloadend = function(e) {

        JsData = this.result;
        console.log('JsData: ' + JsData );  //Check that data has been read
        // try this
        //return JsData;
        // Try Defferred
        return deferred.promise(JsData);

       };
      }, errorHandler);
     }, errorHandler);
    };

    function createDokument(dokName) {
      var ClientTable = '';
      var kake = Cookies.get(dokNavn);
      var visits = JSON.parse(kake);

    $.each(visits, function(index, value) {
      var hente = value.dok + '_' + value.nr;

    //Make sure the variable is blank, for no reason at all
    JsData = '';

    var promise = fetchVisitInfo(hente + '.oln');
        promise.then(function(result) { 
    /// Test if variable has retrieved the data
    console.log('JsData: ' + JsData );

    $.each(JsData, function (i,v) {
      ClientTable += '  <tr>';
      ClientTable += '    <td colspan="3">' + v['orderSum'].Knr + ', ' + v['orderSum'].firma + '</td>';
      ClientTable += '    <td width="3%">' + v['orderSum'].oldV + v['orderSum'].newV + '</td>';
      ClientTable += '    <td width="15%">' + v['orderSum'].newS + '</td>';
      ClientTable += '    <td width="15%">' + v['orderSum'].oldS + '</td>';
      ClientTable += '  </tr>';
  });
 });

});
```

Any ideas ??

Comment: It doesn't look like you return your deferred in the first function.

Comment: Don't you need to define the `onloadend` before (not after) you call `readAsText`?